# Add sorting scope to chain without hitting database twice (Rails, ActiveRecord)

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, scope

I have a chained scope query that checks a tag for flagged items and takes them off of an ‘available’ list. However, this scope is pinned to a ‘visible’ scope:

```
scope :visible, -> { where("rfid_tags.location_id NOT IN (SELECT warehouses.id FROM warehouses WHERE warehouses.deleted_at IS NULL AND warehouses.hidden = 't') OR rfid_tags.location_type = 'Listing'") }
scope :available, -> { not_selected.visible.without_flags }
 scope :without_flags, -> { joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN flags ON flags.rfid_tag_id = rfid_tags.id").where(flags: { id: nil })}
```

I’m trying to order the visible flags so that the flagged items go to the end of the list; a colleague recommended I use something like:

```
scope :available, -> { not_selected.visible.without_flags.ordered }
scope :ordered,  -> (recs) { recs.order('flags.rfid_tag_id NULLS FIRST') }
```

and append it to :visible, but I don’t think I quite understand how to use recs concepts (working on how to pass in an argument)? Trying to join flags on on the :ordered scope gets an error for calling the flags table multiple times. I’m using Rails 4/postgresql. How can I get the ordering using the join table data to settle properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the order to the `with_out_flags` scope.

```
scope :without_flags, -> { 
  joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN flags ON flags.rfid_tag_id = rfid_tags.id")
    .order('flags.rfid_tag_id NULLS FIRST')
    .where(flags: { id: nil })}
```

And then if you ever need to change the order you could use `reorder()`. That will nullify the previously defined order query and use your new one in the reorder clause.

If you still get the error about referencing the flags table too many times, you could use a table alias in your joins and reference that.

```
scope :without_flags, -> { 
  joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN flags f ON f.rfid_tag_id = rfid_tags.id")
    .order('f.rfid_tag_id NULLS FIRST')
    .where(flags: { id: nil })}
```

Comment: I though that might cause other issues, because I had to get it to work independently on `:visible`, but I realized I could create an alternate narrower `:visible_in_cart` scope to chain `:without flags` on independently, which ends up performing better i the UI. Sometimes simpler is better. Thanks for the assist!